# jQuery grabs only the first element in html (in a Django app)

Tags: jquery, django

I have this in a Django app that should allow people to like each photo's comments:

in photo.html:

```
{% for c in comments %}     
    <div class="col-md-3 pull-right">
    {{c.commenter}} Wrote: 
    &nbsp; <span class="grey"> {{c.pub_date|naturaltime}} </span>
    </div>
    <br>

    <div class="col-md-1">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart" id="likecomment" name="{{c.id}}" value="{{c.id}}" title="Like it">
        {{c.likes}}
      </i>&nbsp;
        <i id="likecomment"> </i>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-11">
           {{c.body}}  
    </div>

     <br> 
    <hr>

{% endfor %}
```

and the jQuery to handle it:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#likecomment').click(function() {

        var $this = $(this);
        // To see if jQuery grab the element
        var cid = $('#likecomment').attr('value');


        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/pics/like_comment/" + cid ,
            data: { 
        'cid': cid,
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
            },
            success: likeSuccess,
            dataType: 'html'    
        });            
    });    
});

function likeSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
{     
    $('#likecomment').html(data);
     alert(cid);
}

</script>
```

The views.py:

```
def like_piccomment(request, cid):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        the_comment = PicComment.objects.get(id= cid) 
        the_photo = the_comment.pic
        who_liked = request.user.id

        if PicCommentLike.objects.filter(liker=who_liked, liked=cid):
            the_comment.likes -=1
            the_comment.save()
            PicCommentLike.objects.filter(liker=who_liked, liked=cid).delete()

        else:

            the_comment.likes +=1
            the_comment.save()
            newliker = PicCommentLike(liker=who_liked, liked=cid)
            newliker.save()

    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['likes'] = the_comment.likes
    return render_to_response('userpics/likes.html', args)
```

The strange thing is that this setting works only for the latest comment submitted. No other comment can be liked. 
In fact I don't get the alert when I press like button on any other comments apart from the latest. this is while each comment has its proper name and value as the first comment does.

I really got confused and appreciate your clues.

Comment: you are selecting by an ID. by chance, do you have multiple elements with the same ID?

Comment: Yes all the comments are of the same ID, i.e. 'likecomment', but the  value  and name  of each comment is different.

Comment: that is invalid HTML. the reason jQuery is only grabbing the first one is because there should only be one. you should reformat your HTML and jQuery to use a class instead. it will both be valid, and will suddenly work. ;)

Comment: I am really noob in jQuery. Please elaborate the answer about class-based jQuery and I'll accept it. cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as I mentioned in the comments, you need to modify your HTML first to change the IDs to a class ... something like this:

```
{% for c in comments %}     
    <div class="col-md-3 pull-right">
    {{c.commenter}} Wrote: 
    &nbsp; <span class="grey"> {{c.pub_date|naturaltime}} </span>
    </div>
    <br>

    <div class="col-md-1">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart" id="likecomment" name="{{c.id}}" value="{{c.id}}" title="Like it">
        {{c.likes}}
      </i>&nbsp;
        <i class="likecomment"> </i>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-11">
           {{c.body}}  
    </div>

     <br> 
    <hr>

{% endfor %}
```

And then modify your jQuery to access that class, like this:

```
function likeSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR){     
    $('.likecomment').html(data);
     alert(cid);
}
```

Voila! The key here is that this isn't a jQuery thing ... its an HTML thing. When an ID is assigned to an element, **it must be unique**. Trust me, you violate that rule, and you'll get much more wacky behavior than just jQuery only working on the first one.

Comment: Oh I made a stupid mistake to have multiple html ids. Manythanks for the hint.